# How do I pick up the Enter Key being pressed in JavaFX2?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

I have a TextField to enter a search term, and a button for "Go". But in JavaFX2, how would I make it so pressing the Enter Key in the TextField would perform an action?

Thanks :)

Comment: The Javadoc is a good source for such questions: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html

Comment: Aaah Stack Overflow, as the saying goes:
"Give a person a fish and they eats for a day, 
but teach them to fish and and they'll eat for a lifetime."
But a common SO response is more along the lines of:
"I say, good sir, there is a place with books, 
look up fishing, study and practice hard, 
and 2 months from now you can eat."
Well intentioned, but useless.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the onAction attribute of the TextField and bind it to a method in your controller.

```
@FXML
public void onEnter(ActionEvent ae){
   System.out.println("test") ;
}
```

And in your FXML file:

```
<TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="298.0" onAction="#onEnter" prefWidth="121.0" />
```

Comment: yes, the onAction method seems to be the way to go: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty -> +1 But you need to annotate the onEnter() method with @FXML when "binding" from FXML and it has to take an ActionEvent argument, AFAIK.

Comment: Note that I had to add `(ActionEvent actionEvent)` as a parameter on `onEnter` before it would work.

Answer (score 82):

I'm assuming you want this to happen when the user presses enter only while the `TextField` has focus. You'll want use `KeyEvent` out of `javafx.scene.input` package and do something like this:

```
field.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Using lambda:

```
field.setOnKeyPressed( event -> {
  if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER ) {
    doSomething();
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following:

```
@FXML
public void buttonPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getCode().toString().equals("ENTER"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: better use: `ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER` because it is an enum

Comment: This alone does not work, what is the FXML for this?

Answer (score 4):

Simply using **"lambda expression" :**

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setOnAction(e -> {
    // add your code to be run here
    System.out.println("textFile");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
@FXML public TextField txt;

@FXML
public void textAction(KeyEvent e){

    if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
        System.out.println(txt.getText());
}
```

If for some reason .getCode() is not working, 
make sure you import the library:

```
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
```

NOT

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

I got caught up on this and it was irritating. Im just passing this on for all those in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

On some keyboards you have to put additional tests to the '\n' and '\r' characters.

```
if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER) || event.getCharacter().getBytes()[0] == '\n' || event.getCharacter().getBytes()[0] == '\r') {
        // your action
    }
```