# How to activate the OK button by pressing enter on TextField?

Tags: javafx

I have this class that generates a Alert Dialog with a field to enter a password, and want to activate the OK button when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the password field.

```
public class PasswordDialog extends Dialog<String> {
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    public PasswordDialog(boolean usuario) {
        setTitle("Senha");
        if (usuario == true){
            setHeaderText("Por favor insira a senha do usuário.");
        }else{
            setHeaderText("Por favor insira a senha do administrador.");
        }

        ButtonType passwordButtonType = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(passwordButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setPromptText("Password");

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().add(passwordField);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        HBox.setHgrow(passwordField, Priority.ALWAYS);

        getDialogPane().setContent(hBox);

        Platform.runLater(() -> passwordField.requestFocus());

        setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == passwordButtonType) {
                return passwordField.getText();
            }
            return null;
        });
    }

    public PasswordField getPasswordField() {
        return passwordField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use KeyEvent in JavaFX project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982895/how-to-use-keyevent-in-javafx-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pick up the Enter Key being pressed in JavaFX2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880638/how-do-i-pick-up-the-enter-key-being-pressed-in-javafx2)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should happen by default (at least that's the behaviour on JavaFX 11/Win 10), but you can also close the `Dialog` yourself by calling `setResult` and `close`.

Example closing on arrow keys:

```
// in constructor
passwordField.setOnKeyPressed(evt -> {
    if (evt.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
        setResult(passwordField.getText());
        close();
    }
});
```

---

For closing on pressing enter, use the `onAction` event of the `PasswordField`:

```
// in constructor
passwordField.setOnAction(evt -> {
    setResult(passwordField.getText());
    close();
});
```

---

For more complicated behaviour of the `resultConverter`, you could also use it for setting the result to avoid duplicate code:

```
setResult(getResultConverter().call(passwordButtonType));
```